# Select column called Titel where the id is the same from another Table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Let's call this table `person`:

```
+------+----------+-----------------+------------+-------------+---------------+
| id   | Lastname | Firstname       | created_at | updated_at | Discriminator  |
+------+----------+-----------------+------------+------------+----------------+
|  52  | Bach     | Johann Sebastian| 21732312312|   666666666| Komponist      |
   125 | Beethoven| Ludwig van      | 74197212821| 44444444444| Komponist      |
   84  | Mozart   | Wolfgang        | 57128371293| 33333333333| Komponist      |
   241 | Rossini  | Gioacchino      | 97128371832| 77777777777| Komponist      |
   1   | David    | Beckham         | 97128371832| 77777777777| Member         |
   2   | Messi    | Lionel          | 97128371832| 77777777777| Member         |
   3   | Ronaldo  | Christiano      | 97128371832| 77777777777| Member         |
+------+----------+-----------------+------------+------------+----------------+
```

And this is table `creation`:

```
    +----+----------+---------------+------+
    | id | personId |    Titel      | Name |
    +----+----------+---------------+------+
    |  1 | 52       | Klavierkonzert| Non  |
    |  2 | 125      | Ballade et    | Non  |
    |  3 | 84       | Magnificat    | Non  |
    |  4 | 241      | Overtuer      | Non  |
    |  5 | 1        | Solo          | Non  |
    |  6 | 2        | Homemade      | Non  |
    |  7 | 3        | Random        | Non  |
    +----+----------+---------------+------+
```

I am Pretty new to mysql and databases please be patience.

How Do I select the Titel column in table `creation`, where the id in `person` equals the `personId` in `creation` and the `Discriminator` should be `Komponist`? So no Titels from Members.

Do i need multiple statements to do this?

Comment: Hint:  `INNER JOIN`, `WHERE`.

Comment: thanks alot, i went through a tutorial which clarified my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t1.titel
from creation t1
inner join person t2
  on t1.personId=t2.id
where t2.Discriminator='Komponist'
```

Answer (score 1):

use `inner join, where`  like this

```
select c.Titel 
from Person p inner join Creation c on p.id=c.PersonId
where p.Descriminator='Komponist'
```

Comment: *inner join, where*  are not a operators